# While loop within if statement that is within a foreach loop... not working well

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I hope I can explain this well... I have an array called $departments_ids = array (1, 2, 3).

for each department within the array I need to display a list of comments stored in the database. I came up with something like this:

```
foreach ($departments_ids as $department_id) {

$query = "SELECT page_posts.post_id, page_posts.post, page_posts.post_date_time, 
users.profile_type_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.picture ".
"FROM page_posts ".
"INNER JOIN users ".
"USING (user_id) ".
"WHERE dep_id = $department_id ".
"ORDER BY post_date_time ASC";

$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

     if(mysqli_num_rows($data) != 0) {
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
         Here goes the code to print each comment 
         }
     }
     else {
        <p> Sorry, there are no comments yet. Don\'t  
        be shy, be the first one to post!</p>
        }
}
```

(Note: I ommitted part of the code to simplify the explanation)

The code works well, the problem is that it IS ONLY PRINTING THE FIRST COMMENT FOR EACH DEPARTMENT instead of all the comments stored in the database. 
It's like the code is read only once for each department and then it moves to the next department. 
If I understand this well I believe that once it hits the if statement and sees that there is more than one comment it should continue reading the while statement, and the while statement should take care of all the comments, but for some reason it is not working. I read about people with similar problems, but still can't figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: can we do - where in ( ".implode(',', $department_id)." );

Comment: You used a join. Where are the command for defining how to join those table?

Comment: `Here goes the code to print each comment` - can't you show this code as well?

Comment: `echo mysqli_num_rows($data)` for each iteration to make sure you're getting what you expect. You also need to add some error checking.

Comment: @MarcoMura the `JOIN` is accomplished with [`USING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: you should try moving that query out of the loop. queries within loops are bad. Avoid them when possible

Comment: As @TheBoogieMan said you should try to move the query out, instead you can use `foreach` only for the `WHERE` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments. @TheBoogieMan the problem is that the query needs to be executed for each $department_id so that the comments for each department are displayed. Is there a way to get it out of the foreach loop that I am not aware of?

Comment: @Alex Thanks man. How can I use the foreach for the where clause only? Sorry, I am learning to program.

Comment: If anybody can help me understand why it is printing only the first comment for each department I would greatly appreciate it... The big problem for me is understanding why the "while loop" within the "if" isn't working.... this would help me understand things much better and would help me come up with a better solution.

Comment: @Alex Thanks again: this is what I am getting: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in....  I am studying your code and I do not understand this part: WHERE 1=1

Comment: @rookie `1=1` is a just a statement so you can just add additional conditions `AND` that doesn't do anything, your query returns an empty value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68971/discussion-between-alex-and-rookie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this :

```
$query = "SELECT page_posts.post_id, page_posts.post, page_posts.post_date_time, users.profile_type_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.picture ";
$query .= "FROM page_posts INNER JOIN users USING (user_id) WHERE 1=1 AND";
$query .= "(";
foreach ($departments_ids as $department_id) {
    $query .= " dep_id=$department_id OR ";
}
$query .= ")";
$query .= " ORDER BY post_date_time ASC";

$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($data) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
        /*** Here goes the code to print each comment  */
    }
} else {
    echo "<p> Sorry, there are no comments yet. Don\'t be shy, be the first one to post!</p>";
}
```

Edit :

`$query .= " dep_id=$department_id OR ";`

Is either 1 or 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem... it was a rookie mistake:

I had 2 $query that were conflicting with each other... I had 1 query to look up comments and then another query to look up the responses to those queries... when I removed the second query just to test the code the code I provided in my question worked just fine; therefore,I changed the second query to $query2... problem solved.

Thanks for all your help!